# Simplify multiple similar statements on (while)

Tags: java, module, while-loop, simplify

For example let's say i have this:

```
while( i1 % 1!=0 || i1 % 2!=0 || i1 % 11!=0 || i1 % 16!=0 ||
        i1 % 7!=0 ||i1 % 3!=0 ||i1 % 12!=0 ||i1 % 17!=0 ||
        i1 % 8!=0 ||i1 % 4!=0 ||i1 % 13!=0 ||i1 % 18!=0 ||
        i1 % 9!=0 ||i1 % 5!=0 ||i1 % 14!=0 ||i1 % 19!=0 ||
        i1 % 10!=0 ||i1 % 6!=0 ||i1 % 15!=0 ||i1 % 20!=0 ) {}
```

How can i simplify that?
Like  while the module of i1 for 1-20 is different to 0. without all that mess.
Pardon if its a dumb question, I'm fairly new to this.

Comment: `i1 % 1` always evaluates to 0 unless `i1` is floating point.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a method that will generate the statement for you, and using a `forloop` to iterate 20 numbers and check if the modulo of each number is not equal to zero.

**sample:**

```
    public boolean checkModulos(int toCheck)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            if(toCheck % i != 0)
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

to use it is:

```
while(checkModulos(i1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can work with the statement a bit. With DeMorgan's Law `(!A || !B == !(A &&B))`, you can turn it into `!(i1 % 1 == 0 && i1 % 2 == 0 ... && i1 % 20 == 0)`

Now think about the statement a bit. A number mod another equaling zero means the first number is divisible by the second. That means the statement really reads: not (`i1` is divisible by all the numbers 1-20). So find a number `n` that is divisible by all the numbers 1-20, and have the loop become `while( !(i1 % n == 0) )`, or just `while(i1 % n != 0)`